# Insert an \hline once, after the nth row in pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

In the [pgfplotstable documents](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf), there is an example where you can input `\hlines` in every couple rows:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every nth row={3}{before row=\hline},  % insert hline every 3 rows
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline, after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
]{
a b
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
}
```

[image]

How can I insert an hline once *only* after the third row, instead of every third?

Answer (score 2):

Kinda late, but I had the same problem today.

solved it by:

```
every row no 3/.style={before row=\hline}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add some compilable to make it  easier for us to use your solution?